# Creating regular grid for my data?

Tags: temperature, climate-models, earth-system, geospatial, grid-spacing

I have daily spatiotemporal  data with covariates at 10 different locations. My question is ***is it possible to convert my data*** into a grid format?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm no expert, but I'm guessing that even the experts would have trouble understanding what you mean. A few more sentences of explanation would really help.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "Yes". But if you want more help you'll need to give a *lot* more detail on what you're trying to do, and perhaps what tools you have to do it.

Comment: Please do expand.  My mental image right now is taht you have 10 locations with a whole bunch of data for each one.  10 points isn't much of a grid.  When I've used digital elevation models, I've found that you have to be at least two rows from the edge to get reasonable interpolations (bicubic)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it will not be a very good dataset. You will only be limited to the size of the dataset.

You can use Python's [griddata function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html). But of course, you will need to make your grid before using the function. Or you can use the [interp2d function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d).